# hello, I can’t solve this problem, I want to run this command, there is such an error?

Tags: django, wagtail, loaddata

python manage.py loaddata --settings `definme.settings.dev django-dump.json`

wagtail.models.i18n.Locale.DoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture Locale matching query does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that isn't enough information to help you. The error message is saying you are missing some locale information. For anyone here to help you we need to know how you created your `django-dump.json` file and the status of the database you are importing into.

Comment: here i ran this command always it worked



python definme/manage.py dumpdata --settings definme.settings.dev -a > django-dump.json

Comment: And the site from which you are dumping the data is identical to the site you are loading into? I am assuming the source site is working just fine. If the source site works and you are dumping everything, I don't know why the import isn't working.

Without details all I can say is look at your dump file and see what locale is desired and then figure out why it doesn't exist.

Comment: I lost weight there

I threw off the weight there mistake,

how can i send you a dump and database in sql

Comment: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6663

Comment: this is also the same error

Answer (score 0):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/definme/manage.py", line 10, in 
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 102, in handle
self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 163, in loaddata
self.load_label(fixture_label)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 253, in load_label
if self.save_obj(obj):
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 209, in save_obj
obj.save(using=self.using)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 281, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 841, in save_base
pre_save.send(
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
return [
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in 
(receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 368, in set_locale_on_new_instance
instance.locale = Locale.get_default()
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 61, in get_default
return cls.objects.get_for_language(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 34, in get_for_language
return self.get(
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
wagtail.models.i18n.Locale.DoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture '/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/django-dump.json': Locale matching query does not exist.
(venv) noro@Norayrs-MacBook-Air definme % python definme/manage.py loaddata  django-dump.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/definme/manage.py", line 10, in 
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 440, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 102, in handle
self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 163, in loaddata
self.load_label(fixture_label)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 253, in load_label
if self.save_obj(obj):
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 209, in save_obj
obj.save(using=self.using)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 281, in save
models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 841, in save_base
pre_save.send(
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 176, in send
return [
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in 
(receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 368, in set_locale_on_new_instance
instance.locale = Locale.get_default()
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 61, in get_default
return cls.objects.get_for_language(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wagtail/models/i18n.py", line 34, in get_for_language
return self.get(
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
wagtail.models.i18n.Locale.DoesNotExist: Problem installing fixture '/Users/noro/Documents/Ongrid/definme/django-dump.json': Locale matching query does not exist.

Comment: The 2 things I would check are that you have configured `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` and have a default locale. Then I would look in the JSON file to see if it has any locale data or if it will be trying to use the default locale

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).